# Handling email sending and response in Nextjs server actions with Nodemailer and React Email

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, nodemailer

I have a project in Next.js that has to send emails, it's working fine but the problem is that if I want to check whether the email I want to send goes through or not, it fails. This is what I have:

```js
await transporter
    .sendMail(options)
    .then((info) => {
      console.log("Email sent:", info.response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Email not sent:", error);
    });
```

And it works fine, but when I want to return a response, it fails because of this:

```
error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:266:61)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

What I want to figure out is how to do this:

```js
await transporter
    .sendMail(options)
    .then((info) => {
      console.log("Email sent:", info.response);
      return NextResponse.json({ status: "sent" });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Email not sent:", error);
      return NextResponse.json({ status: "error" });
    });
```

I guess the error is due to the async, but I can't find any other way to do it.

Comment: @AdrianMole it seems like we have the same error output but the solution provided for his issue doesn't work on my end. In fact that's what I already tried before posting here. But thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, not it the best way but here are my two cents:

```js
let isSent = false;

await transporter
    .sendMail(options)
    .then((info) => {
      console.log("Email sent:", info.messageId);
      isSent = true;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Email not sent:", error);
    });

  if (isSent) {
    return NextResponse.json({ status: "sent" });
  } else {
    return NextResponse.json({ status: "error" });
  }
```

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the asynchronous response. Anyway, this works.